# What's the meaning of "for" in "the weather forecast is for sun"

Tags: prepositions, word-in-context

> The weather forecast is for sun, with intermittent showers.

I gather it wants to say "the weather forecast tells people it's sunny with intermittent showers". But I couldn't understand this part "for sun". I guess 'sun' is the written abbreviation of 'sunny'(though I didn't find this usage in the dictionary). Even if so, what's the meaning of "for" here? Does it mean something like "support"? That's the only meaning I could imagine, though it's weird.

How to explain this part "for sun"?

Answer (score 2):

If *for = in support of* seems "weird" in this context, try thinking of it as *heading **for**, pointing in the direction of*, as in [*"I'm for bed"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I%27m%20for%20bed%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl). But I think it's just as "intuitive" to see OP's example as short for...

> *The weather forecast is **for it** (the weather) **to be** sun/sunny*.

Note that there's no real need for a preposition at all in OP's exact context, and semantically it's irrelevant whether it's ***sun*** or ***sunny*** (both are perfectly valid and commonly used).

Comment: Precise interpretation of individual prepositions is for the birds.

Comment: Is that a reference to [this](http://homes.chass.utoronto.ca/~dresher/col9.html)?

Comment: Coincidentally, I was reading in New Scientist last night about [a breakthrough in understanding "dolphin-speak"](http://www.newscientist.com/article/mg22129624.300-dolphin-whistle-instantly-translated-by-computer.html#.U5oeXXC-qPY), and I must say at the time I thought there couldn't be much to it if they've taken 25 years to capture a single instance of a truly "symbolic" dolphin whistle. Obviously they would have done better to have spent that time helping [Christian Moullec working with geese](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PP4cCAbey0o).

Comment: Oh, wow. just wow.

Comment: In this case, I think the usage is not entirely grammatically correct, but such usage is pretty common. It could also be "The weather forecast is for sunshine" -- or "sunny skies".